# C# Run macro without opening Excel

Tags: c#, office-interop

Is there a way to run a macro using Office Interop without launching the Excel application?

If i set the Excel application to false it will still show Excel

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application oExcel = new Excel.Application();
    oExcel.Visible = false;

    oExcel.Run("'c:\\PERSONAL.XLSB'!Module1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to have MS Office, particularly Excel installed in case you want to run Excel Macros. Server Side Automation of MS Office is not recommended. Please see this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0).